# How fix error when using Leaflet's TileLayer.NoGap and styled WMS layers from GeoServer?

Tags: leaflet, geoserver, wms

A governmental agency has a WMS layer and I want to display it on my leaflet canvas.

I add this code:

```
 var wmslayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/depo/wms',{
                layers:'nep'
            }).addTo(mymap);
```

This works fine. The layer is displayed. Now, the layer comes with two styles: "brightbackground" and "darkbackground". When I open the layer in QGIS I can select and add any of the styled layer. But when I add `styles : 'darkbackground'`  to the code, like this:

```
 var wmslayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/depo/wms',{
                layers:'nep',
                styles:'darkbackground'
            }).addTo(mymap);
```

I get an error saying:
`L.TileLayer.NoGap.js:224 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.`

If I comment out the plugin "NoGap" I don't get any errors, but also not getting any wms-layer, unless I remove `styles : 'darkbackground'`. Then layer returns.

Any ideas how to use the style that comes with the WMS-layer? Is there anything I can do in Geoserver? Or can I serve it from any other place? Or are there any plugin that might help?

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried `layers:'nep:darkbackground'` maybe it works

Comment: [Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please. I'm guessing the WMS server is returning some error on some tiles; using the [network monitor of your browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) to see the requests and responses from the WMS server should give more info about what's going on.

Comment: BTW https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.TileLayer.NoGap/issues/6

Comment: IvanSanchez, you are correct - it does return a bunch of XML. On every tile actually. The returned type is "vnd.ogc.se_xml". When I open the XML file I get this:

`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException code="StyleNotDefined">
      No such style: darkbackground
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
`

Comment: Falke Design - When I do that I get similar respons as above, but with message ``` Could not find layer depo:darkbackground```.